# JavaScript New page when document reached end of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found some open source code and was using it to create invoices. The code is awesome and creates a page like the below photo:

---

[image]

---

But, if I keep adding elements and it gets to the end of the page, it does not create a new page and just cuts information off (See photo below). How can I get the script to make a new page when the content reaches the end of current page?

---

[image]

---

Here is that HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="license" href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license/">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Invoice</h1>
            <address contenteditable>
                <p>Jonathan Neal</p>
                <p>101 E. Chapman Ave<br>Orange, CA 92866</p>
                <p>(800) 555-1234</p>
            </address>
            <span><img alt="" src="logo.png"><input type="file" accept="image/*"></span>
        </header>
        <article>
            <h1>Recipient</h1>
            <address contenteditable>
                <p>Some Company<br>c/o Some Guy</p>
            </address>
            <table class="meta">
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>101138</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Date</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>January 1, 2012</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount Due</span></th>
                    <td><span id="prefix" contenteditable>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="inventory">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Item</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Description</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Rate</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Quantity</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Price</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Front End Consultation</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>Experience Review</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>150.00</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>4</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a class="add">+</a>
            <table class="balance">
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Total</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount Paid</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Balance Due</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <h1><span contenteditable>Additional Notes</span></h1>
            <div contenteditable>
                <p>A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</p>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    /* Shivving (IE8 is not supported, but at least it won't look as awful)
/* ========================================================================== */

(function (document) {
    var
    head = document.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement,
    elements = 'article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output picture progress section summary time video x'.split(' '),
    elementsLength = elements.length,
    elementsIndex = 0,
    element;

    while (elementsIndex < elementsLength) {
        element = document.createElement(elements[++elementsIndex]);
    }

    element.innerHTML = 'x<style>' +
        'article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}' +
        'audio[controls],canvas,video{display:inline-block}' +
        '[hidden],audio{display:none}' +
        'mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}' +
    '</style>';

    return head.insertBefore(element.lastChild, head.firstChild);
})(document);

/* Prototyping
/* ========================================================================== */

(function (window, ElementPrototype, ArrayPrototype, polyfill) {
    function NodeList() { [polyfill] }
    NodeList.prototype.length = ArrayPrototype.length;

    ElementPrototype.matchesSelector = ElementPrototype.matchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.oMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function matchesSelector(selector) {
        return ArrayPrototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(selector), this) > -1;
    };

    ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelectorAll = ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.mozAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.msAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.oAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    function ancestorQuerySelectorAll(selector) {
        for (var cite = this, newNodeList = new NodeList; cite = cite.parentElement;) {
            if (cite.matchesSelector(selector)) ArrayPrototype.push.call(newNodeList, cite);
        }

        return newNodeList;
    };

    ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelector = ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.mozAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.oAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitAncestorQuerySelector ||
    function ancestorQuerySelector(selector) {
        return this.ancestorQuerySelectorAll(selector)[0] || null;
    };
})(this, Element.prototype, Array.prototype);

/* Helper Functions
/* ========================================================================== */

function generateTableRow() {
    var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');

    emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>0.00</span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable>0</span></td>' +
        '<td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>0.00</span></td>';

    return emptyColumn;
}

function parseFloatHTML(element) {
    return parseFloat(element.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d\.\-]+/g, '')) || 0;
}

function parsePrice(number) {
    return number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1,');
}

/* Update Number
/* ========================================================================== */

function updateNumber(e) {
    var
    activeElement = document.activeElement,
    value = parseFloat(activeElement.innerHTML),
    wasPrice = activeElement.innerHTML == parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(activeElement));

    if (!isNaN(value) && (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.wheelDeltaY)) {
        e.preventDefault();

        value += e.keyCode == 38 ? 1 : e.keyCode == 40 ? -1 : Math.round(e.wheelDelta * 0.025);
        value = Math.max(value, 0);

        activeElement.innerHTML = wasPrice ? parsePrice(value) : value;
    }

    updateInvoice();
}

/* Update Invoice
/* ========================================================================== */

function updateInvoice() {
    var total = 0;
    var cells, price, total, a, i;

    // update inventory cells
    // ======================

    for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.inventory tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
        // get inventory row cells
        cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');

        // set price as cell[2] * cell[3]
        price = parseFloatHTML(cells[2]) * parseFloatHTML(cells[3]);

        // add price to total
        total += price;

        // set row total
        cells[4].innerHTML = price;
    }

    // update balance cells
    // ====================

    // get balance cells
    cells = document.querySelectorAll('table.balance td:last-child span:last-child');

    // set total
    cells[0].innerHTML = total;

    // set balance and meta balance
    cells[2].innerHTML = document.querySelector('table.meta tr:last-child td:last-child span:last-child').innerHTML = parsePrice(total - parseFloatHTML(cells[1]));

    // update prefix formatting
    // ========================

    var prefix = document.querySelector('#prefix').innerHTML;
    for (a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) a[i].innerHTML = prefix;

    // update price formatting
    // =======================

    for (a = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-prefix] + span'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) if (document.activeElement != a[i]) a[i].innerHTML = parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(a[i]));
}

/* On Content Load
/* ========================================================================== */

function onContentLoad() {
    updateInvoice();

    var
    input = document.querySelector('input'),
    image = document.querySelector('img');

    function onClick(e) {
        var element = e.target.querySelector('[contenteditable]'), row;

        element && e.target != document.documentElement && e.target != document.body && element.focus();

        if (e.target.matchesSelector('.add')) {
            document.querySelector('table.inventory tbody').appendChild(generateTableRow());
        }
        else if (e.target.className == 'cut') {
            row = e.target.ancestorQuerySelector('tr');

            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }

        updateInvoice();
    }

    function onEnterCancel(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        image.classList.add('hover');
    }

    function onLeaveCancel(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        image.classList.remove('hover');
    }

    function onFileInput(e) {
        image.classList.remove('hover');

        var
        reader = new FileReader(),
        files = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files : e.target.files,
        i = 0;

        reader.onload = onFileLoad;

        while (files[i]) reader.readAsDataURL(files[i++]);
    }

    function onFileLoad(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;

        image.src = data;
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('click', onClick);

        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateNumber);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', updateNumber);

        document.addEventListener('keydown', updateInvoice);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', updateInvoice);

        input.addEventListener('focus', onEnterCancel);
        input.addEventListener('mouseover', onEnterCancel);
        input.addEventListener('dragover', onEnterCancel);
        input.addEventListener('dragenter', onEnterCancel);

        input.addEventListener('blur', onLeaveCancel);
        input.addEventListener('dragleave', onLeaveCancel);
        input.addEventListener('mouseout', onLeaveCancel);

        input.addEventListener('drop', onFileInput);
        input.addEventListener('change', onFileInput);
    }
}

window.addEventListener && document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onContentLoad);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify when you want to break your pages in your print with this CSS property.

`page-break-after: always;`

I'm not familiar with the plug-in you're using, but keep references to page number and row counts and insert a css class in your `<tr>` where you want to page break in your print.